# Creating JIRA issue through angular form

Tags: rest, angular, jira, jira-rest-api

Trying to create an issue from angularjs using rest api throwing 403 forbidden error. New to this, any help would be appreciated.

error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://jira.ab.com/rest/api/2/search',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +
            btoa('abc@ab.com' + ":" + '***'));
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        jql: {
            project: "JQR",
            maxResults: 20,
        }
    })
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
}, function errorCallback() {
    console.log("Error calling API")
});
```

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Enable-CORS-in-JIRA-REST-API/qaq-p/553997

Comment: Thanks for your rly @DanielHilgarth .. am not touching confluence i want to create issue in jira directly through rest api

Comment: Read the question carefully. They are doing the same. Their Javascript executes inside Confluence, but that doesn't change anything.